# position relative div wrapping input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A little warning: I'm just starting out with css and js/html.

I'm trying to get a wrapper to wrap around a text box. As I understand it, divs without explicit dimensions wrap their content (height/width: auto). I'm using jquery to wrap an element element with a wrapper for a label. I'd like it to wrap the entire input box (as I believe it should considering the input box is within the div), but it doesn't seem to be as simple as wanting...

For some reason, I can't get the properties of my wrapper to change after setting them - even using the Chrome JS console. So even going in and manually setting the height of the wrapper div to 40 doesn't change anything.

Here's the fiddle everyone so far has been asking for - there's not much more to this question. I just want the div to wrap the input, which it isn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/5vBz4/

As far as I know, my input styles aren't conflicting, either:

```
input.floatlabel {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is what I have so far, and the result. 
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: We also have **A little warning**: we won't feel excited answering some **HTML-related** question without any fiddle. Of course some will feel OK.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but remove `display: inline` from the `.wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want:

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vBz4/2/)

Comment: Or perhaps `inline-block` if you want to keep the width as small as necessary. Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/5vBz4/3/

Comment: @SpoonNZ this worked. I'm just wondering why it enforced the height to what it did, to be honest.

Comment: Because CSS isn't always as straight forward as it might seem... :)